# Can't figure out how to remove the unnecessary space at end of div

Tags: html, css

Here's the template I'm using: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ElasticContentSlider/
Source here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/02/26/elastic-content-slider/

Closest I've gotten is changing the height of '.main' but it changes the size of the main content box.

Comment: isn't that what you want (change the size of the main content box)? how else would you remove the space at the end of the div without changing the size of the box.. clarify what you mean.

Comment: do you mean the space under the box that is creating the vertical scroll?

Comment: @0x0700: check my answer,the answer you accepted will mess up the design later

Answer (score 1):

try to put a `html, body, .container, .main {overflow:hidden;}` the is the best solution for you bro...

Comment: Just note that with this solution, if someone reduces the browser window under about 600px, your main box will start to cut off.

Comment: @0x0700 you can add a query to remove the design when it reach under 600px '@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) html, body, .container, .main{overflow:auto !important;}'

Answer (score 0):

to remove the extra space change your css to something like this:

```
body .container { height:72%;}
.cbp-contentslider { height:100%;}
```

To simplify the layout even further I would suggest:

```
 body .container { height:66%;}
.cbp-contentslider { height:100%;}
.main, .container > header { padding:0; width:82%; } // Don't need such padding for .main just use width/margin
```

Comment: But if you add more content than the window size.. wouldn't you want a scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need

```
.cbp-contentslider li > div {
position: absolute;
top: 9em;
bottom: 3.313em;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
padding: 0 1em;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;  //changed this from `auto` to `hidden`
}
```